# How to check blockchain in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm try to learn a Hyperledger Composer.
now, Hyperledger Composer's sample test is working.
How to check blockchain in Hyperledger Composer?, have a some visual tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is a development framework and suite of tools that is oriented towards accelerating the ability to write blockchain applications as a developer primarily. It simplifies and expedites the creation of blockchain applications. If you're new to Blockchain, Hyperledger Fabric or Hyperledger Composer, we recommend that you start with the tutorials like the Developer tutorial at the [Hyperledger Composer website](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html).

The present Hyperledger Explorer (shows blocks as they're added etc) is being updated to work with v1 of Hyperledger Fabric I understand https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

You therefore don't use composer tools or APIs to get a list of blocks - you need Fabric SDK REST APIs for that. This can help you -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest - some parts are work in progress. But the salient point is the chaincode ID is the business network ID, where deployed Composer business networks are concerned. eg.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
9982c1c7e84b        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-vehicle-lifecycle-network-0.11.3   "chaincode -peer.a. " etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see every step what composer is doing in the logs. Command is => "docker logs ". you will get container name using "docker ps -a" command(orderer plays an important role).